How to approach my autistic friend regarding his negative behavior?
I have a close friend who is autistic.  We have been friends for over 20 years.  Over time he has made increasingly disparaging comments about me and I am unsure of how to address this.
My friend was identified as autistic at an early age and underwent behavioral modification (treatments specifically designed to treat the effects of autism).  If you were to casually encounter him while doing everyday tasks you probably would not know that he is autistic. He carries on a fairly normal life and is successful in an intellectually challenging job involving a fair number of business associates.
However, if you spent a significant amount of time with him you may notice that his social interactions are, odd -- he has a certain awkwardness or anxiety in the way he behaves.  He is also a bit egocentric and seems to lack some insight into his and other's behavior.  Please note that I am not an expert on autism and I am not directly attributing these traits / behaviors to everyone who is autistic. But, I have heard that people with autism may miss certain social cues.
Over time he has made increasingly disparaging remarks towards me.  For instance, I arranged a large social gathering, but suffered a severe headache as the night progressed.  His date noticed that I was suffering from a headache.  My friend's response to this observation was, "Englishman Bob always has something wrong with him. I wouldn't pay any attention!"  There have been other instances like this.  I have indirectly referenced these remarks and he seems to get the hint for a brief period of time (several weeks?).
I don't believe that my friend understands that what he's being outrightly cruel.  My strategy for dealing with issues like this with other associates would be to drop a few hints here or there that I don't like a given behavior.  If these hints go unnoticed I would probably resort to classic assertiveness -- I'd likely wait until a less stressful time and say, "Hey, when you do 'X' I feel 'Y.' Could you maybe change your behavior?  Or maybe there something I could do differently?"
I am hesitant to communicate via classical assertiveness with him do to the lack of insight into how he and others behave.  Are there strategies or suggestions on how I could address his behavior?

So you say that your friend has actually understood you (at least for a period of time) when you have mentioned such remarks to him previously.  Why wouldn't you simply do so again?  Why do you feel you have to be indirect?  Especially since you think he's going to miss normal social cues, that would imply you'd need to be more direct, not less.

You don't have to be friends with someone, especially if they cause you sadness. Would seeing this person less be an option you would consider?

@Stian it appears that is the most likely option.

Your conclusion that "He is also a bit egocentric" may be an assumption applicable more to the neuro-typical. I call the spectrumy obliviousness "Self-absorbed." It's a defense mechanism, not selfishness.

I believe your analysis of the situation is spot on. Hints aren't going to work because his mind is likely to be too busy to deal with them at the time.
What you call classical assertiveness seems to be the best approach. It's awkward having to ask him explicitly, but a time when the both of you are relaxed is the best time to discuss such things. Make a point of treating it like a puzzle to be solved rather than assigning blame. At the end of the day, disparaging remarks say more about the person making them than about the person receiving them, so you may want to ask how he thinks it reflects on him in the eyes of others.

For someone who doesn't pick up quickly on social cues, and doesn't really understand hints to react appropriately to it, polite and direct communication is often the best way to reach them.
So you shouldn't shy from being assertive here. But remember that assertiveness isn't about getting your way - especially in an inter-personal situation. It is about trying to understand each other, acknowledging the rough edges of each other's personality without judgement and learning to navigate around it to preserve (and perhaps even earn) mutual respect.
So one way to approach this situation would be to try and understand why he is disparaging towards you. Instead of just saying,

Hey, when you do 'X' I feel 'Y.' Could you maybe change your behavior? ...

you could first ask him for clarification - "When your GF pointed out to you that I was having a bad headache, why exactly did you remark that 'I always have something wrong with me'? Do you really believe that I often act like that to seek attention from others?". Depending on how the conversation goes, you could also discuss other specific previous incidents when he made disparaging remark against you. You could then also point out to him that these hurt you. To introspect about oneself, through another person's eyes is not easy. Sometimes he may say something critical that may be or may not be valid and genuine and you will automatically feel defensive. Or you may not understand him or he may be uncommunicative. Either way, you will be able to get some idea of whether he is just ignorant, disinterested in learning social skills or in building a stronger friendship with you or just plain mean. You can then make a better decision on what to do next.
(My first assumption on reading about the particular incident was that perhaps he got jealous of the attention his gf was giving to you and thus he reacted with a mean remark at you, as a coping mechanism).
Ofcourse, all this also depends on what kind of relationship you want with someone and how much effort you want to put into it. Let's face it, it takes time and patience to get to know someone and be comfortable with them while we all grow and change. There is nothing wrong in just taking a step back from an existing relationship that you feel has stagnated due to the other person's unwillingness to change or acknowledge your feelings.
